# Johannburkard Highlight Script not loading

Tags: jquery

We have implemented this external JS `https://johannburkard.de/resources/Johann/jquery.highlight-5.js`. But this external site is not loading. Can you please guide me?

Please let me know if there is any option to resolve this issue.

Comment: Contact the owner of the site and ask them to fix it?

Comment: This is why you don't refer to external URLs (i.e. steal their bandwidth) for resources you need.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled around and found a copy of what **I believe** is the script you're looking for; it's reproduced here for your convenience. You should host it on your own site.

```
/*

highlight v5

Highlights arbitrary terms.

<http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html>

MIT license.

Johann Burkard
<http://johannburkard.de>
<mailto:jb@eaio.com>

*/

jQuery.fn.highlight = function(pat) {
 function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
  var skip = 0;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
   var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
   pos -= (node.data.substr(0, pos).toUpperCase().length - node.data.substr(0, pos).length);
   if (pos >= 0) {
    var spannode = document.createElement('span');
    spannode.className = 'highlight';
    var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
    var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
    var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
    spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
    middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
    skip = 1;
   }
  }
  else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
   for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
   }
  }
  return skip;
 }
 return this.length && pat && pat.length ? this.each(function() {
  innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
 }) : this;
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function() {
 return this.find("span.highlight").each(function() {
  this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
  with (this.parentNode) {
   replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
   normalize();
  }
 }).end();
};
```